# Open set and basis in Topology

Tags: general-topology

How is the following set open:

An example of open set is $(-1,1) \times [-1,1]$. Prove that the given open set is a basis for $X= \mathbb{R}$ (with standard topology) $\times \mathbb{R}$ (with discrete topolgy) .

My understanding is $[-1,1]$ is closed so how can it be open. I just couldn't get past the first sentence let alone proving that it is a basis. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: In the discrete topology, singleton sets are open. Hence, any set is open; including $[-1,1]$. For your second question, what is it supposed to be a basis for?

Comment: The emphasized paragraph makes no sense as it stands. If you’re quoting exactly, your source is dreadfully confused, but I suspect that you’re not quoting (or paraphrasing) correctly.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: It was just $X=\mathbb{R}$ with standard topology but I wanted to know in both cases. But, I have made the edite accordingly. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: It still makes no sense: $(-1,1)\times[-1,1]$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R$, so it can’t possibly be an open set in $\Bbb R$ under either topology. And what is the ‘it’ in ‘Prove that it is a basis’? The pronoun has no clear antecedent in what you’ve written.

Comment: I guess you want $(a,b)\times[c,d]$ to be a basis for the product topology. It is not. What about $(a,b) \times \{c\}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I just heard one of the students giving this as an example but didn't know how this was possible. So, I am trying to find out. I have made some more edits!

Comment: $\{(-1,1)\times[-1,1]\}$ is not a base for the standard topology on $\Bbb R^2$, and the set $(-1,1)\times[-1,1]$ is not open in $\Bbb R^2$ with the standard topology. Either the other student was badly confused, or you’ve misunderstood something that was said.

Comment: A subset is not a basis. A basis has to be a family of sets.

Comment: @AndréCaldas: I have misinterpreted the questions. I have made edits accordingly. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I have made changes which I think should make it clear. Sorry, for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ denote $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, and let $Y$ denote $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology. It is true that the set $(-1,1)\times[-1,1]$ is open in $X\times Y$, because $(-1,1)$ is open in $X$, and $[-1,1]$ is open in $Y$. The latter is true because **every** subset of $Y$ is open in $Y$: that’s what the discrete topology is.

The set of all products of the form $(a,b)\times[c,d]$, where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$, $a<b$, and $c\le d$ is a base for the product topology on $X\times Y$. To see this, let $U$ be any non-empty open set in $X\times Y$. By the definition of the product topology this means that for each point $p=\langle x,y\rangle\in U$ there are an open set $V_p$ in $X$ and an open set $W_p$ in $Y$ such that $p\in V_p\times W_p\subseteq U$. Since $p\in V_p\times W_p$, we know that $x\in V_p$ and $y\in W_p$. The open intervals form a base for the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, so there must be $a,b\in\Bbb R$ such that $x\in(a,b)\subseteq V_p$. The singletons (one-point sets) form a base for the discrete topology on $\Bbb R$, so $[y,y]$ is an open set in $Y$ such that $y\in[y,y]\subseteq W_p$. Thus,

$$p=\langle x,y\rangle\in(a,b)\times[y,y]\subseteq V_p\times W_p\subseteq U\;.$$

This shows that every open set in $X\times Y$ is the union of sets of the form $(a,b)\times[y,y]$ for $a,b,y\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$, so it’s certainly true that every open set in $X\times Y$ is the union of sets of the form $(a,b)\times[c,d]$, where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$, $a<b$, and $c\le d$. Moreover, each set of the form $(a,b)\times[c,d]$, where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$, $a<b$, and $c\le d$ is open in $X\times Y$, so the family of all such sets is indeed a base for the product topology on $X\times Y$.

Comment: It makes much more sense ow. Thank you!

Comment: @JamesBond: You’re welcome! Glad to help clear things up.